# pass recyclerView image and data to next activity

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

how to pass data and image from recyclerView item click to the next activity ? i tried and success for only pass data. Failed to pass image using byteArray. Need help for pass data and image for recyclerView item click.

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<DataAdapter> dataAdapters;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){
        super();
        this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        DataAdapter dataAdapterOBJ =  dataAdapters.get(position);
        imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl(),
ImageLoader.getImageListener(Viewholder.VollyImageView,
                        R.drawable.ic_vector_loading,
                        R.drawable.ic_vector_error
                )
        );

Viewholder.VollyImageView.setImageUrl(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl(),imageLoader)           Viewholder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageTitle());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView ImageTitleTextView;
        public NetworkImageView VollyImageView ;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ImageTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView) ;
            VollyImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VolleyImageView) ;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http://192.168.0.101/jsonimage/ImageJsonData.php";
    String Image_Name_JSON = "image_title";
    String Image_URL_JSON = "image_url";
    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;
    RequestQueue requestQueue ;
    View view ;
    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();
        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TITLE", ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
      @Override
 public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){

        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }

    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
       GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));                  ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));
                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }
  recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

Another two class ImageAdapter.java and DataAdapter.java

Comment: are you trying to pass online image?

Comment: yes , trying to pass image from recyclerview

Comment: don't pass bitmap , pass image link to next activity